# HTML Form button press twice to open new page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple login using form, i create a form that has input field for user to key in password and then the user press submit button

the password will be retrieved using javascrip, if the password is correct it will open a new page

```
<script language="javascript">
   function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
   {
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
       if(form.password.value == "nopassword")
       {
           self.location='main.html'
       }
           else
       {
           alert("Wrong Password\nTry again Bak Choy Friend! :)")/*displays error message*/
       }
    }
</script>
.
.
.
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Login" onclick="check(this.form)"/>                  
</form>
```

But the problem is it requires the user to press twice instead of one before it can open a new page? 
the first time, i press the button with the password, the address bar displays

...net/?password=nopassword

then, the 2nd time i press the button with the password, it will redirect me to the new page
may i know how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Checking password in javascript? What kind of security it is?

Comment: what do you mean by " it requires the user to press twice" ? What is your question?

Comment: It should work with one click, for making it more clear tell what's the `main.html` file? and what's the name of this file in your platform? And for your knowledge, In javascript you should put a `;` in the end of executing lines of code.

Comment: @MostafaR Ha, don't open the ```;``` can of worms here

Comment: yes, What kind of security it is? :)

Comment: thanks, i just want to test out javascript about the getting variable from html! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
 /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
   if(form.password.value === "nopassword")
   {
      self.location = 'main.html';
      return true;
   }
       else
   {
       alert("Wrong Password\nTry again Bak Choy Friend! :)")/*displays error message*/
       return false;
   }
}
</script>

 <input type="button" class="button" value="Login" onclick="return check(this.form);"/>
```

Comment: yup i did work using your method! 
but is this because of cookie problem?